# Fit a DataTable into a shinydashboard box

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, shinydashboard

I have read all of the answers to similar questions, and none of them worked. Very simple question: how do I get the datatable to fill the box? Here's a reprex:

```
## UI

ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(disable=TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    
    tabsetPanel(
      
      tabPanel("Main Tab",
               fluidRow(box(title = "Test",width=6,column(12,DTOutput("table1")),height=400)
                        ),
               )
    )
    
  )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
      iris %>% 
        datatable(options = list(dom = "t", scrollX = TRUE))
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That doesn't work, but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be using `scrollY` argument:

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(disable=TRUE),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    
    tabsetPanel(
      
      tabPanel("Main Tab",
               fluidRow(box(title = "Test",width=6,column(12,DTOutput("table1")),height=400)
               ),
      )
    )
    
  )
)

# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    iris %>% 
      datatable(options = list(scrollX = TRUE,
                               scrollY = "200px"))
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: wow. simple as that!